# Django: skip system check when running custom command

Tags: python, django

I've added a custom management command to an application developed using Django 1.6.11. This command, let's call it `initdb`, performs a set of particualr actions:

- Checks whenever a database and user from settings.py exist and if not create them, set appropriate character sets, grants access, etc.
- Performs `syncdb`
- Loads particular database dump

In other words, it's very handy for quick database initialization from total zero.

Now, I'm migrating to Django 1.8.5 and one thing I've noticed is that, before almost every command, Django automatically executes `check` command from new system check framework, which among other stuff checks if database/user form `settings.py` exist. That leads to a situation when I can't run my custom command because automatic check throws exceptions that there is no access to database (indeed, my custom command should create it).

Is there any way to force skipping automatic `check` that Django makes, at least in custom management command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, and this is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.requires_system_checks); set the `requires_system_checks` attribute to False in your Command subclass.