# Django migration - disable system checks

Tags: django, django-migrations

I upgraded from Django 1.7 to Django 1.9. I have a number of migrations. Since the upgrade I can no longer create a fresh database.

The problem is that "django manage.py migrate" runs checks. The checks import the application urls. These ultimately import code that looks up the database.

I can get the migration to work, by modifying the migrate.py script and adding this line (as per [Django: skip system check when running custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349574/django-skip-system-check-when-running-custom-command)):

```
 requires_system_checks = False
```

Is there a standard/supported way to prevent the system checks via a command line parameter, or is there a way to know that I am running in a management command during the url loading so that I can exclude the web-serving parts of the system?

Comment: Disabling the system checks is the wrong solution. You need to make sure that you don't execute any queries when importing modules. This is just one of the issues this can cause.

Comment: @knbk And what about model checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way in the [3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/) version, there is a flag called [--skip-checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-skip-checks) which skips running system checks prior to running the command.