# django: don't register ModelAdmin (exclude module-level code) when running makemigrations / migrate

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-migrations, django-modeladmin

I have made multiple changes to an existing django model (added new foreign key relation, etc). **Before** creating and applying these changes with manage.py makemigrations / migrate, I adapted the corresponding admin module's ModelAdmin for that app to reflect these unapplied changes.

Running makemigrations now fails with "ProgrammingError: {new_field} does not exist". I figure this happens because when makemigrations runs system checks, the ModelAdmins in admin.py are registered (executing queries on non-existant models that I try to create with the migrations).

**Question**: Is there any straight-forward way to exclude the ModelAdmins from being registered when running manage.py makemigrations / migrate without disabling system checks in total (see [Django migration - disabel system checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35792376))?

I can solve the problem by deleting my admin.py modules when running makemigrations / migrate and recreating them afterwards. There is really no need to check the admin modules when migrating, but I guess this will happen when registering ModelAdmins on the module-level of admin.py (as in the examples in the [django admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/)). I do not use a custom AdminSite.

**On more general terms**: is there any straight-forward way to exclude specific top-level module code from being executed when running a specific manage.py command like makemigrations or migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a reasonable way to do this.

Since I was so desperately searching for a django-native way to check for the current command, I did not think of simply evaluating the command line arguments  like normal to do this.

When calling makemigrations or migrate from the command line, I can get the name of the command with `sys.argv[1]`. This should work in any top-level code that is automatically executed when django runs system checks.

The registering of ModelAdmins is caused through `django.contrib.admin.autodiscover()`, which is automatically called when using the default `AdminConfig` (i.e. when `django.contrib.admin` is included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting). We can use `django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig` in the setting instead, so that `autodiscover()` will not be called automatically (see [django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig)).

I changed the corresponding part in my `settings.py` from

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
   "django.contrib.admin",
    ...
]
```

to

```py
MIGRATION_COMMAND = sys.argv[1] in ('makemigrations', 'migrate')
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
   "django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig" if MIGRATION_COMMAND else "django.contrib.admin",
    ...
]
```

This way, all the `admin.py` modules of my apps will be ignored when running makemigrations / migrate.
I can now also use the custom `MIGRATION_COMMAND` setting anywhere else if I need to.